# How to use fonts having space in C# windows form to create excel workseet?

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, closedxml

I am using an `IEnumerable` variable to create an Excel worksheet in C# windows form application. The problem is that I can set created worksheet font if the font name has 1 word, ex. 'IRNazanin', but for font name with space it doesn't work, ex. 'B Mitra'. My code is:

```
var wb = new XLWorkbook { RightToLeft = true };
var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("Sick_Information");
ws.Columns().AdjustToContents();
ws.Style.Font.FontName = "B Mitra";
```

I have tried using font name:

- without spase, ex. "BMitra"
- with a hyphen, ex. "B-Mitra"
- with underline, ex. "B_Mitra"
- with extra single qout, ex. "'B Mitra'"

Still not working.
I am using `ClosedXML.Excel` library with `ClosedXML` version `0.94.2.0` and MS Office 2016. The excel will get the font name but won't apply it.

[image]

True `B Mitra` font is like this. (Changed manually)

[image]

The customer needs file with `B Mitra` font and Persian numbers. So I have no choice to change the font.

Comment: Is it excel interop? please add the tag for library name.

Comment: @RezaAghaei it is `ClosedXML.Excel` library.

Comment: I tried [ClosedXML package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML) version 0.95.0-beta2 (latest) and 0.94.2 (latest stable) package and it works as expected. Tried `"B Nazanin"` which doesn't exists on my system and `"Times New Roman"` which exists on my system.

Comment: My `ClosedXML.Excel` version is `0.91.0.0`.

Comment: Try using the latest or latest stable version.

Comment: I have upgraded my `ClosedXML` version to `0.94.2.0` but still not working.

Comment: Fix the font in Excel, save the file, rename it to `.zip`, open it, find `styles.xml`, open that and find the way the font name is stored. Use that in ClosedXML.

Comment: @FrancoisBotha I did what you said. In `styles.xml` file, font value is `<name val="B Mitra"/>`. I copy and paste it in my code. But still not working

Comment: Please log an issue on the Github repo and I'll look into it when I'm back from holiday.

Comment: Have you tried going to C:/Windows/Fonts and checking what the filename is for B Mitra? Perhaps if you try that filename without extension, it will work? Also, have you tried other fonts that you can verify exist within C:/Windows/Fonts with spaces in the font name?

Comment: @Lennart yes I have tried that. It doesn't work for all fonts with space in their name like 'B Nazanin' which is a Persian font.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/182039/how-to-change-some-of-the-numbers-in-word-to-be-arabic-numbers-within-word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"B Mitra"` is a valid font name, but you also need to change `FontCharSet`:

```
cell.Style.Font.SetFontName("B Mitra");
cell.Style.Font.SetFontCharSet(XLFontCharSet.Arabic);
```

ClosedXML uses `XLFontCharSet.Default` by default. Output Excel file shows correct font name, but doesn't display cell content properly:

[image: font]

I used Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool for Microsoft Office to inspect Excel file. With `XLFontCharSet.Arabic` there is a line there:

```
FontCharSet fontCharSet6 = new FontCharSet(){ Val = 178 };
```

And content is displayed as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ClosedXML library then try use setFontName method:

```
ws.Style.Font.SetFontName("B Mitra");
```

Comment: When i tried with like font names Bell MT, Berlin Sans FB and Gill Sans MT then it's worked. My excel version 2016 and CloseXML version 0.93.1

Comment: I have Office version 2016 and `ClosedXML.Excel` version `0.91.0.0`